# app engine Application Identifier Alias

Tags: google-app-engine

I understand and have seen Google App engine migration to High Replication.

At the end of the process GOOGLE sets up the alias.
Can this be done manually by me?

How can I set an alias up on an application in Google App Engine?
The reason for wanting to do this is I am converting to HRD by copy and controlling the whole event myself.

Can I set the alias myself from somewhere in the admin screen?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can control WHEN the alias is set?

Comment: How do you set an alias on an application?

Comment: You don't set it. It's automatically created for you, and set to the app-id of the application you are migrating from. Such that all old_app_id.appspot.com traffic is routed (not redirected) to new_app_id.appspot.com.

Comment: So the only way to set it is by the migration tool. I like things to be tidy and converting to HRD will cause a name change of the APP at ID level but of course the original will be redirected to the new name. It will remain like that for ever and ever and ever....

Comment: Why do you want to do the migration manually? This is exactly what the migration tool is for.

Comment: Because the Migration tool will only run ONCE!

Comment: I also run migration from a copy of the original application. Since the migration tool cause several problems in the HRD application, some things _had to_ be done by hand, and I also wanted to let a few users test the application before I migrated everyone.
It is annoying that manually creating an alias is not possible. Now I can only alias the copied application to the HRD application.
Google, can you please do something about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally assign your application to another, the alias is mis-assigned.  Being able to reverse this sort of misdirection would be useful, but it doesn't look like that functionality is available.

Comment: This should have been a comment